# Sort week wise data by date in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to sort data by date though the script only has week wise data.

Given below is a sample SQL:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(CONCAT('Week', ''), 
         EXTRACT(WEEK FROM sale_date ::date + '1 day'::interval)
        ),
  COUNT(*)
FROM sales
WHERE sale_date between '2018-12-29' AND '2019-01-04'
GROUP BY CONCAT(CONCAT('Week', ''), 
                EXTRACT(WEEK FROM sale_date ::date + '1 day'::interval)
               )
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

The above script runs just fine but when it sort the final output it sorts Week1 first and Week 52 last, rather I am trying to sort by the actual date such that W52 appears first (since it 2018-12) and W1 appears last.

Current output:

```
Week1,101
Week52,2350
```

Expected output:

```
Week52,2350
Week1,101
```

I am using Amazon Redshift DB.

Comment: Change `ASC` to `DESC`

Comment: @MichałTurczyn that's a quick trick however in future when the date range in the query is the same year then it would not work out

Answer (score 0):

This may be OK for you, it requires adding an extra column to the query

```
select date_trunc('WEEK',sale_date ::date + interval '1 day'),
  CONCAT(CONCAT('Week', ''),
              EXTRACT(WEEK FROM sale_date  ::date + '1 day'::interval)),
       count(*)
from sales
where sale_date  between '2018-12-29' and '2019-01-04'
group by date_trunc('WEEK',sale_date ::date+ interval '1 day'),
         CONCAT(CONCAT('Week', ''),
                EXTRACT(WEEK FROM sale_date  ::date + '1 day'::interval))
order by date_trunc('WEEK',sale_date ::date+ interval '1 day') asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT week, count FROM (
    SELECT week, MAX(sale_date) max_date, COUNT(*) count FROM (
        SELECT sale_date,
            CONCAT('Week', EXTRACT(WEEK FROM sale_date::date + '1 day'::interval)) AS week
        FROM sales
        WHERE sale_date between '2018-12-29' AND '2019-01-04'
    )
    GROUP BY week
) ORDER BY max_date ASC
```

Would get strange results if the space every exceeded a year though.